# Pass variable from event handler to another method

Tags: c#, .net, events, methods, event-handling

I am working on a .NET application that gets message from a serial port (Arduino) which is received by an event handler. However I am unable to pass the message that is stored by the event handler to another method. Currently the event handler that receives the data is looking like this:

```
private static void MessageReceivedHandler(object sender, SerialDataReceivedEventArgs e)
{
    SerialPort serialPort = (SerialPort)sender;
    string received_data = serialPort.ReadExisting(); // pass received_data to another method
}
```

I want the `received_data` variable to be passed to another method named `getMessage()`. This method will execute some operations using the received data which will then be returned. The `getMessage()` will be called from another class, thus these operations can not be implemented in the event handler.

**EDIT :** Sorry, missed an important point here. I want the received_data to be available in getMessage without getting it from the parameter. That is because another class needs to access the getMessage exactly as it is now without only `(out output_data)` as parameter.

```
public bool getMessage(out output_data)
{
    bool success = true;
    // This is the part I do not understand how to implement
    string input_data = received_data; 

    try{

        // Do operations with the input_data (which is the data from event handler).
    } catch (Exception e)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(e.ToString());
        succcess = false;
    }

    output_data = input_data;
    return success;
}
```

I assume it is possible to have the `received_data` as a global variable and then read/write to it accordingly. However, this is not a good approach, so I would like some advice in order to find a good solution.

Comment: Why don't you invoke *getMessage* in *MessageReceivedHandler* ?

Comment: Can you explain what goes wrong when you use `getMessage(received_data);`, which would be the obvious way to pass that data to that method?

Comment: You could put your string into a queue within the even handler and have the getMessage fetch data from it.

Comment: @L.B Do you have an example of how I can invoke getMessage in the handler?

Comment: @oerkelens ```received_data``` is a local variable in the handler and is not exposed to the other methods. Or did I not understanding your point correctly?

Comment: @Mrchacha It was especially the fact that your `getMessage` had a different signature before you edited that made your question seems very strange. It was `public string getMessage(string input_data)` so it would make sense to anyone to use the _input_ parameter that you mentioned.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you don't want to use the received_data as a parameter i believe your best choice is the global variable. 
But you can still use with parameters if your only problem is that you need this method being called from somewhere else. A more complicated way your method to be used with the parameters:

```
    public bool getMessage(out output_data, String received_data, bool receivedDataNeeded)
{
    bool success = true;
if(receivedDataNeed){
        // This is the part I do not understand how to implement
        string input_data = received_data;
    try{

    // Do operations with the input_data (which is the data from event handler).
    }catch (Exception e){
    Console.WriteLine(e.ToString());
    succcess = false;
    }
}else{
    string input_data = "Whatever you need to initialize it to";
    try{

    // Do operations with the input_data (which is the data from event handler).
       } catch (Exception e){
         Console.WriteLine(e.ToString());
         succcess = false;
       }
}
        output_data = input_data;
        return success;
}
```

When you call the getMessage from the handler you can call it like this:

```
getMessage(output_data, received_data, true);
```

When you want to call it from somewhere else that you don't need the received_data as parameter you can call it like this:

```
getMessage(output_date, "", false);
```

Comment: Thanks for the tip. Since the getMessage method only will be called from outside the class, the received_data will not be used as a parameter. Thus I will need to implement received_data as global variable right?

Comment: Then i believe yes. I can't think of another way to pass your string. The most convenient solution i believe is the global variable.